# Transfer from one scene to another in actionscript-3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am working on an `adobe flash` project and I want my code to transfer me from `scene 1` to `scene 2` when clicking on a button on `scene 1`.

Comment: Try to avoid scenes. It can cause lots of troubles (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7eb3a.html).

Answer (score 6):

Are you familiar with gotoAndPlay(frameNumber);
It is extended with gotoAndPlay(frameNumber, sceneName);

So if your scene is called Scene 2 then in as3 typ:

```
gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
```